# ListView scrollbarStyle with margin/padding

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollbar

Hopefully a simple one. 
v4.0.3

I have a `ListView` and want to leave a margin of 10dip right and left. 
The content is easy of course, but I want the divider line to have a 10dip margin right and left too.

If I add `android:PaddingRight` or `android:layout_marginRight` to the `ListView` or the `LinearLayout` which contains the ListView then this works of course, but the List scrollbar which appears down the right hand side as you scroll the list also moves in by the padding/margin distance.

I want the scrollbar indicator to remain.
I've tried all the `android:scrollbarStyle`settings.

Comment: You can also use: android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay". outsideInset puts your scrollbar outside of defined padding. "outsideOverlay" puts it inside the padding, ie looks more like google play app. This also works on gridview btw.

Comment: you can add an answer to your own question and mark it as correct

Answer (score 11):

Can do easily

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvDonorDetails"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"/>
```

Or

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvDonorDetails"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may create new scrollbar thumb drawable what do you want about scroll drawable margin and padding.

Use these attr

```
android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/your_drawable"
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/your_drawable"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of scrolling the list view. putting inside a scroll view is limiting the list view to load only one row when we want to load the list dynamically,but at last got the solution :
include

```
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack= "true"
```

and

```
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

properties inside the ListView Tag.

Answer (score 0):

To have an equal margins (around and between) ListView items without having the scrollbar overlaying the ListView items, you can use the following code:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"/>
```